# Extension to of a problem from Rudin to unbounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

The question that has been asked here for several times in various forms is somewhat like this (cf. the following links):

> [Nonzero $f \in C([0, 1])$ for which $\int_0^1 f(x)x^n dx = 0$ for all $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16831/nonzero-f-in-c0-1-for-which-int-01-fxxn-dx-0-for-all-n)

Also,

> [Integral of a continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158716/integral-of-a-continuousfunction?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Again,

> [Prove that $f(x) = 0$ on the interval $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596114/prove-that-fx-0-on-the-interval-0-1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

And so on!!

Now just being curious I am asking for similar result **(BUT on unbounded domain)** if at all true, in the form of following problem:

> Suppose $v \in C([0,\infty))$ and $v$ vanishes at infinity. If $v$ is assumed to be square integrable and $lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{0}^{x}(x-y)^{k} v(y) dy = 0 \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}\cup{0}$, can we **prove** or **disprove** that **$v$ is identically equal to 0** ??

Any form of solution/discussion is much appreciated!!

Comment: I'm sorry, I deleted my previous answer because in the end I couldn't solve it after the mistake you pointed out in my attempted solution. It seems like this is a hard problem. In case you find a solution I'd be glad if you posted the solution here.

Comment: Hello Lorenzo and anybody who is interested... but I suggest you to google a bit about "Ghost matrices and a characterization of symmetric Sobolev bilinear forms" by Kwon et al. See equation 2.7 and 2.8. I HOPE this is our sought after counterexample. Cheers.